# Changing the Directory to pwd in Ruby gives "No such file or directory" error?

Tags: ruby

I used the command

```
Dir.chdir(`pwd`)
```

but got the error message

```
No such file or directory
```

I tried outputting `` `pwd` `` and it is correct. In fact when I pass the current path as an argument to the program and use `chdir` command everything works fine. So what could be the problem?

Comment: Why would you want to change the current directory to the current directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `pwd` ends with a linebreak, `\n`. `` Dir.chdir(`pwd`.chomp) `` would get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

The *problem* is running an external command to do something so simple.  You're already a program: [do it yourself](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Dir.html#method-c-getwd).  Then you don't have to deal with the subtleties explained by steenslag.